# Task return type gives not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I have a method implemented from an interface which looks as follows..

```
public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
     if (user == null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
     }
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello Task library!"); }); 
     //I even tried
     //Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello Task library!"); });

}
```

The above code gives me an error not all code paths return a value.

Comment: return Task.Factory.StartNew(....

Comment: Just mark the `CreateAsync` method as `async`. You don't actually want to return anything. `async Task` is the async equivalent of `void`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Needs a `return` :

```
 return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello Task library!"); });
```

Or better:

```
return Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello Task library!"); });
```

Comment: For more info on 'better', you might want to read [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 6):

returning `Task.CompletedTask` is cleaner.

```
public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
  if (user == null)
  {
     throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
  }

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello Task library!"); }); 
   // other operations

   return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `Task` in the name of your method denotes the return value of this method.

Therefore the compiler expects at a certain point your method a `return` statement where you return an object of that type that you denoted in the name.

```
public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{

     if (user == null)
     {
         // this part of code will return from the method with an exception
         throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
     }

     // but this part of code is also expected to return something
     return Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello Task library!"); });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using a **synchronous** Task function.

For **asynchronous**, you're not required to return anything. The `async` keyword transforms the method and constructs the returned Task instance.  Read here:

[Where is the return statement in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268120/where-is-the-return-statement-in-async-await)

For example,
here's a situation where you could run multiple tasks asynchronously operating on a list of IDs. This is done by adding the each task to a list of tasks and then releasing them to be run concurrently:

```
private static List<Task> tasks = new();

public static async Task DoTask(int id)
{
    // do something with id
}

public async Task RunTasks()
{
    try
    {
        foreach(var id in IDList)
        {
            var result = DoTask(id);
            if (result != null)
            {
                 tasks.Add(result);
            }
            else
            {
                 // null task 
            }
        }
        await tasks.WhenAll(tasks);
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     {
         //Exception
     }
}
```

`WhenAll()` will wait for all tasks to complete even in the presence of failures.

Answer (score -1):

Needs a return ..if possible one inside the if condition also and one outside